# Erro nos índices de um array

Tags: java, array, algoritmo, classificação

Estou tentando fazer um algoritmo de *selection sort*, só para treinar algoritmos mesmo, ao meu ver minha lógica está certa quanto a ordenação, mas ele está me retornando um erro que não entendo.

Código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class AlgoritmosOrdenacao {


static int[] SelectionSort(int vet[]){
    int aux, menor;
    for (int i=0; i<vet.length-2; i++){
        menor = vet[i+1];
        for (int j=i+1; j<vet.length-1; j++){                
            if (menor > vet[j+1]){
                menor = vet[j+1];
            }
        }
        aux = vet[i];  
        int idx = Arrays.asList(vet).indexOf(menor);
        vet[i] = menor;            
        vet[idx] = aux;            
    }
    return vet;
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    // INPUT DO VETOR
    int vet[] = new int[5];
   Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
   for (int i=0; i<vet.length; i++){
       vet[i] = teclado.nextInt();
   }
   // PRINT DO VETOR ANTES DA ORDENAÇÃO
   for (int z=0; z<vet.length; z++){
       System.out.printf("Vet[%d] = %d\n", z, vet[z]);
   }
   SelectionSort(vet);

   // PRINT DO VETOR DEPOIS DA ORDENAÇÃO
   System.out.println("Depois da ordenação");
   for (int z=0; z<vet.length; z++){
       System.out.printf("Vet[%d] = %d\n", z, vet[z]);
   }
}
```

E o erro completo é esse:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at algoritmosordenacao.AlgoritmosOrdenacao.SelectionSort(AlgoritmosOrdenacao.java:48)
at algoritmosordenacao.AlgoritmosOrdenacao.main(AlgoritmosOrdenacao.java:69)
C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 5 segundos)
```

Na linha: `int idx = Arrays.asList(vet).indexOf(menor);` o Netbeans sublinha `vet` e dá a seguinte sugestão:

> array de primitiva confuso especificado para o método vararg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está em `Arrays.asList(vet)`. Quando você passa um array de `int`, [o resultado é um `List<int[]>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1467913) - ou seja, uma lista de `int[]` (de arrays de `int`), e não uma lista de `int`. Exemplo:

```
int v[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
for (Object obj : Arrays.asList(v)) {
    System.out.println(obj.getClass().isArray());
}
```

Estou usando `getClass()` para obter a classe de cada elemento da lista, e em seguida uso o [método `isArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isArray()), que verifica se a classe em questão representa um array. A saída é:

> true

`true` é impresso apenas uma vez, pois a lista retornada por `Arrays.asList` só possui um elemento: o array de `int`. Se quiser, pode verificar o tamanho da lista usando o [método `size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size()):

```
int v[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(v).size()); // 1
```

Este código imprime "1", pois a lista só possui um elemento (o array de `int`).

De qualquer forma, como os elementos desta lista são arrays, `indexOf` não encontrará o `int` que você está passando. `indexOf` verifica se o `int` é um elemento da lista, mas como a lista só possui um array como elemento, o `int` não é encontrado (o fato do `int` estar dentro do array não importa, `indexOf` não encontrará o `int`).

E quando ele não encontra o elemento, [o retorno é -1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)):

```
int v[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(v).indexOf(2)); // -1
```

E ao tentar acessar a posição -1 do array (`vet[idx]`, sendo que `idx` é -1), ocorre o erro de `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, já que as posições de um array começam em zero (não há posições negativas).

---

Como você quer obter o índice do menor elemento, basta setar este valor quando você encontrá-lo. Não há motivo para criar uma nova lista e percorrê-la a cada iteração (além de ser desnecessário, é extremamente ineficiente ficar criando uma nova lista a cada iteração).

Se você setar o valor do índice quando o menor elemento for encontrado, não precisará criar a lista toda hora:

```
static int[] selectionSort(int vet[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vet.length - 1; i++) {
        int indiceMenor = i; // indiceMenor começa com o índice do elemento atual
        for (int j = i + 1; j < vet.length; j++) {
            if (vet[j] < vet[indiceMenor]) { // vet[j] é menor que o "menor atual"
                indiceMenor = j; // índice do menor passa a ser j
            }
        }
        int menor = vet[indiceMenor];
        vet[indiceMenor] = vet[i];
        vet[i] = menor;
    }
    return vet;
}
```

Repare também que dei uma mudada no algoritmo, e também coloquei o nome do método começando com letra minúscula, seguindo as [convenções de código do Java](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, me esclareceu bastante além de ter aprendido algo novo também, muito obrigado mais uma vez. =D

Answer (score 2):

Bom, Isso significa que está tentando pegar o elemento que está no index "-1", porem não existe
O que está acontecendo:

Nesta linha `Arrays.asList(vet).indexOf(menor);` o `indexOf` não está encontrando o menor valor na lista, e quando acontece isso essa função retorna -1.

Sendo assim nesta linha `vet[idx] = aux;` está dando a exceção `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` que informa que está sendo acessado um elemento em um indice que não existe, como o array começa em 0 não tem como acessar o -1.

Para resolver isso sugiro guardar o índice do menor valor, junto com ele.

Assim esta linha:

```
menor = vet[i+1];
```

deveria ser modificada para

```
menor = vet[i+1];
idxMenor = i+1;
```

e esta linha:

```
menor = vet[j+1];
```

para:

```
menor = vet[j+1];
idxMenor = j+1;
```

Assim não precisa converter o array para lista e encontrar novamente o valor (o que por sinal é muito mais custoso, porque procurar as informações que estão um pouco mais acima no código?)

Answer (score 1):

Na linha Arrays.asList(vet).indexOf(menor) o indexOf não estava encontrando o menor valor na lista e retornava -1.

Tente o seguinte código para fazer sua ordenação correta:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AlgoritmosOrdenacao 
{

    static int[] SelectionSort(int vetor[]){
        int aux = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < vetor.length; j++)
            {
                if (vetor[i] < vetor[j])
                {
                    aux = vetor[i];
                    vetor[i] = vetor[j];
                    vetor[j] = aux;
                }
            }
        }
        return vetor;
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
            // INPUT DO VETOR
            int vet[] = new int[5];
           Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
           for (int i=0; i<vet.length; i++){
               vet[i] = teclado.nextInt();
           }
           // PRINT DO VETOR ANTES DA ORDENAÇÃO
           for (int z=0; z<vet.length; z++){
               System.out.printf("Vet[%d] = %d\n", z, vet[z]);
           }
           List<int[]> a = Arrays.asList(vet);
           System.out.println();

           SelectionSort(vet);

           // PRINT DO VETOR DEPOIS DA ORDENAÇÃO 2
           System.out.println("Depois da ordenação 2");
           for (int z=0; z<vet.length; z++)
           {
               System.out.printf("Vet[%d] = %d\n", z, vet[z]);
           }
    }
}
```