# Adicionar elementos de array em ArrayList e imprimir os valores

Tags: java, arraylist

Tenho duas dúvidas em relação ao `ArrayList`:

1. Tem alguma maneira que eu possa iniciar os valores sem precisar ter que usar o `.add` toda vez? Por exemplo, o vetor normal usa `int vetor[5]={1,2,3,4,15}` e coloca os valores dentro do colchetes. No `ArrayList` tenho que  usar:

   ```
   vetor.add(1);
   vetor.add(2);
   etc...
   ```
2. Como faço para imprimir todos valores de um `ArrayList`? No vetor usa-se laço de repetição, não consegui isso no `ArrayList`.

Comment: Todas as respostas deram opções aternativas de como fazer a inicialização de um ArrayList já com elementos mas nenhuma deu a resposta a pergunta do usuario, que é **não, não é possivel iniciar ArrayList diretamente com valores como se faz com um array comum**.

Comment: @ArticunoL Realmente, eu (e os demais também, pelo jeito) foquei tanto em "como fazer" que em não me atentei a este detalhe. Eu atualizei minha resposta com essa informação :-)

Answer (score 4):

No Java ainda não é possível inicializar um `List` da mesma forma que um array, usando a sintaxe `int v[] = {1, 2, 3}`. [Existe até uma proposta para que a linguagem tenha este recurso](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/186), mas por enquanto a única maneira é usar métodos da API nativa (listados abaixo e nas outras respostas).

#### Criar a lista

Você pode passar os valores diretamente para o método [`java.util.Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-):

```
List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 15);
```

Caso você já tenha um array de [`java.lang.Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) com os valores, também é possível passá-lo diretamente, como já foi dito nas outras respostas:

```
Integer v[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 15 };
List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(v);
```

**Mas atenção**, se o array for de `int` (e não de `Integer`), isso não vai funcionar:

```
int v[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 15 };
List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(v);
```

Na verdade o código acima nem compila. Isso acontece porque, quando `asList` é chamado com um array de `int` (e não de `Integer`), o retorno é um `List<int[]>` (uma lista de arrays de `int`, ou seja, uma lista na qual cada elemento é um array), como já explicado [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/353329/112052). E como estou atribuindo o retorno de `asList` em um `List<Integer>`, o código não compila.

Neste caso, o jeito é fazer o bom e velho *loop*, adicionando os valores um a um:

```
int v[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 15 };
List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i : v) {
    lista.add(i);
}
```

A partir do Java 8 também é possível usar *streams*:

```
int v[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 15 };
List<Integer> lista = Arrays
    // cria o stream
    .stream(v)
    // convert int para Integer
    .boxed()
    // transforma em uma List
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Primeiro eu uso o método [`stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-), que por estar recebendo um `int[]`, retornará um [`java.util.stream.IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html). A seguir, o método [`boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--) converte cada `int` para o respectivo `Integer`. E por fim, o método [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) recebe um *colector*. No caso, [`java.util.stream.Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) faz com que a *stream* seja "coletada" para uma lista, resultando em um `List<Integer>`.

---

A partir do **Java 9** também é possível usar [`java.util.List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-):

```
// List.of() disponível no Java >= 9
List<Integer> lista = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 15);
```

As mesmas observações de `Arrays.asList` também se aplicam: se passar um array de `int` como parâmetro, o retorno será um `List<int[]>`, então ele só funciona se passar um array de `Integer`.

A diferença é que [`List.of` retorna uma lista imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243874/112052), enquanto `Arrays.asList` não:

```
// List.of() retorna lista imutável
List<Integer> lista = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 15);
// se tentar modificar elementos, lança java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
lista.set(0, 9);

// Arrays.asList() retorna lista mutável
List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 15);
// posso modificar elementos sem problemas
lista.set(0, 9);
```

Há outras diferenças listadas [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46579348).

#### Imprimir a lista

O jeito mais fácil é simplesmente imprimir a lista inteira:

```
System.out.println(lista);
```

Isso imprime todos os seus elementos de uma vez:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 15]

Mas se você quiser imprimir um de cada vez, sem as vírgulas e colchetes, etc, faça um `for`:

```
for (Integer i : lista) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Neste caso, irá imprimir um por linha:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   15

Comment: Baseado na resposta linkada, então o `List.of` vai duplicar a memória usada quando comparado com o `Arrays.asList`?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Pelo que vi no código fonte do JDK, `Arrays.asList` mantém a referência ao array original, enquanto `List.of` cria uma cópia do array.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Na verdade parece ser mais complicado. [Se tiver até 2 elementos](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/8645b4aed22f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/List.java#l1030), `List.of` [só guarda as referências](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/8645b4aed22f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ImmutableCollections.java#l177), mas se tiver 3 ou mais, aí [o array é copiado](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/8645b4aed22f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ImmutableCollections.java#l223)

Comment: `List1` e `List2` contém, respectivamente, 1 e 2 posições de memória, então continua valendo o "duplicar memória", quando referente ao conteúdo. Mas é interessante o fato de que ele trabalha diferentemente para esses casos

Answer (score 2):

Podes criar o Array da mesma maneira

```
Integer[] integerArray = {1,2,3};
```

E depois converter para `ArrayList` tirando partido da biblioteca `java.util.Arrays`:

```
List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(integerArray);
```

Para imprimir, podes usar um `foreach` em vez de um `for`:

```
  for (Integer integer: integerList) {
      System.out.println(integer);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o método `addAll()` de `java.util.Collections`. Este método adiciona todos os elementos em uma coleção específica.

**Exemplo:**

```
 Integer vetor[]={1,2,3,4,15};

 ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();

 Collections.addAll(myList, vetor);
```

Para iterar sobre a lista utilize o `foreach`

**Exemplo:**

```
for(Integer n: myList){
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Veja em funcionamento no [Codingground](http://tpcg.io/QkkJMS).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma lista imutável, porém não é possível alterá-la e está disponível a partir do Java 9.
Exemplo:`List<Integer> integers = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4);`

Outra forma é criar um array e adicionar na lista utilizando um enhanced-for.
Exemplo:

```
Integer[] integers = {1, 2, 3, 4};
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();

//Enhanced-for
for(Integer value : integers){
    integerList.add(value);
}
```

Fazendo conforme está acima é possível utilizar o método remove.
Caso você fosse utilizar o método asList, por exemplo, você não conseguiria remover algum item da lista. Exemplo:

```
List<Integer> integersList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
integersList.remove(1); //Lança a exceção java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

O número 1 no método remove corresponde ao índice da lista.

Answer (score -1):

Podes criar o Array da mesma maneira

Integer[] integerArray = {1,2,3};

E depois converter para ArrayList tirando partido da biblioteca java.util.Arrays:

List integerList = Arrays.asList(integerArray);

Para imprimir, podes usar um foreach em vez de um for:

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).